# Restrict access to files if targeted directly

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, security, restriction

I have a  basic folder structure like this:

```
index.php
assets/
  docs/
    document.pdf
includes/
  script.php
```

I need to be able to block access to the document if someone was to try and get it directly, for example: `www.domain.com/assets/docs/document.pdf` but allow access if was to be linked from the index.php page.

Would there be a way I can block access like this, or, is there a method of embedding the pdf on the page? I'm open to using PHP or jQuery if it can be done through that as well.

Some of the methods I have tried have been including deny restrictions in the htaccess but then that obviously blocks it altogether.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Referer header directly in your Apache configuration (an `assets/docs/.htaccess` file will do):

```
SetEnvIf Referer "domain\.com" is_local_referer
<FilesMatch "\.pdf$">
    Require env is_local_referer
</FilesMatch>
```